# How to keep child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="parentDiv">

    <div id="childDiv">This is child Div</div>

</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$("#childDiv").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

It will remove everything. How can I keep the child div?

Comment: $('div.parentDiv').replaceWith($('#childDiv'));

Comment: $("#childDiv").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().replaceWith(this);
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to remove the element's parent from the DOM but still keep your element intact.:

```
$("#childDiv").click(function() {
    $(this).unwrap();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#childDiv").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().replaceWith(this);
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) in your case,

```
var xParent;

$("#childDiv").click(function() {
   xParent = $(this).parent().detach();
});
```

and use that xParent in the places whereever you want.